# Trying to apply a struct to a multidimensional array of Dates for a collapsable tableview Swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, tableview, collapsable

I'm trying to apply this struct

---

```
struct expandableWeeks {
    var isExpanded: Bool
    let dates: [Date]
}
```

---

To a multiDimensional array of Dates

```
var twoDWeeksArray = [[Date]]()
```

The example I followed on YouTube the array was populated with strings set in the code
but all of my data for the array is populated at run time where do I apply this?

This is how the example was done:

```
var twoDimensionalArray = [ExpandableNames:(isExpanded: true, names: ["Amy", "Bill", "Zack"]),
                           ExpandableNames:(isExpanded: true, names: ["Carl", "Chris"])]
```

Can it be applied when the variable is initialized or when I am populating the Array in my function?

```
func getTwoDWeeksArray() {
    twoDWeeksArray.removeAll()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy" 
    var firstYear = dateFormatter.string(from: dailyEntry[0].date!)
    var tempEntry = ""
    var z = 0
    twoDWeeksArray.append([weeksArray[0]])
    if weeksArray.count == 1 {
        return
    }
    for x in 1...weeksArray.count-1 {
        tempEntry = dateFormatter.string(from: weeksArray[x])
        if tempEntry == firstYear {
            twoDWeeksArray[z].append(weeksArray[x])
        } else {
            firstYear = tempEntry
            twoDWeeksArray.append([weeksArray[x]])
            z = z + 1
        }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: I would call that function you have from `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: the function is called from viewDidLoad()  it won't let me add the struct to the initialization of the array. it says :   '[date].type' is not convertible to '[date]' swift

Comment: var twoDWeeksArray =[ ExpandableNames:(isExpanded: true, names: [Date]]() does not work

Comment: Why should it work, why are you even doing that when you have a function that should fill the array?

Comment: if you look at( Expandable and Collapsible Sections UITableView (Ep 3)) on YouTube   at the 12:00 mark this is what im trying to do   trying to apply the struct to where I initialize the multi dimensional array  and its not working.   i might have to leave the      let dates: [Dates]  out of the struct. I don't know? im lost

Comment: You should use `var twoDWeeksArray = [[Date]]()` and nothing else

Comment: then how do I apply the struct to the array I've tried everything I know.

Comment: So your end goal is an array of structs? I didn’t get that. Will the Boolean always be set to the same value initially?

Comment: the struct adds the properties to the contents of the array,  (isExpanded:, dates:) and is used to keep track of the number of dates in that section of the array because after you delete that section of the array to close it then when you open it back up the numbers in the index don't match up and it crashes  I just don't understand why swift won't let me apply the struct to where im defining the array like this          var twoDWeeksArray = [expandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: [Date]]).   it gives me a  '[Date].Type' is not convertible to '[Date]' error

Comment: thank you for your help, someone just answered it in my other post.  [ExpandableWeeks(isExpanded: true, dates: [Date]())] works